# Fill options of select tag

Tags: javascript, html

In my `HTML` file I have a `select tag` in which when I select the first one, another `select tag` should fill out with some options, and when select the other option, some others options will fill out in the other `select tag`.

I did that in my HTML :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillWirelessChannel(){
            var index;
            var selectTag= document.getElementById('wirelessChannel');                       selectTag.options.length = 0; // wireless should 
            selectTag.options.length = 0; 
            var auto = document.createElement("option");
            auto.value= 'auto';
            auto.innerHTML = 'auto';
            if (document.getElementById('country').selected="1") {
                  for(index=4920; index<=5825; index+=5){
                      var opt = document.createElement("option");
                      opt.value= index;
                      opt.innerHTML = index;     
                      selectTag.appendChild(opt);         
                  }
              } else if(document.getElementById('country').selected="2"){               
                  for(index=4920; index<=6075; index+=5){
                      var opt = document.createElement("option");
                      opt.value= index;
                      opt.innerHTML = index;       
                      selectTag.appendChild(opt);           
                  }
              }
        }
    </script>
```

The wirelessChanne is the select tag must fill.
The country tag is in the if statement and the selected one is our condition.
Now when I run the code, the second if does not work.( It does not display till 6075 in the second statement ) and also does not add auto option to the select tag.( I want to display auto in the first option of the wirelessChannel without conditions, I mean at the first index it should be displayed auto)
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are never adding *auto* to *selectTag*

Comment: for one thing you are using a single`=` sign in the logic test where you should be using a double `==`

Comment: Option elements don't contain markup, so setting their *innerHTML* property is inappropriate. Set the *text* property instead. "Tags" belong in markup, the DOM has elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the If statement  Use `==` instead of `=`. For adding an option auto to the select append that before your for loop.You have created the option but forgot to append the option.Use `selectTag.appendChild(auto);` befor the for loop

```js
 fillWirelessChannel();

function fillWirelessChannel(){
            var index;
            var selectTag= document.getElementById('wirelessChannel');                       selectTag.options.length = 0; /* wireless should */
            selectTag.options.length = 0; 
            var auto = document.createElement("option");
            auto.value= 'auto';
            auto.innerHTML = 'auto';
            selectTag.appendChild(auto);     
            console.log(document.getElementById('country').value);
            
            if (document.getElementById('country').value=="1") {
                  for(index=4920; index<=5825; index+=5){
                      var opt = document.createElement("option");
                      opt.value= index;
                      opt.innerHTML = index;     
                      selectTag.appendChild(opt);         
                  }
              } else if(document.getElementById('country').value=="2"){               
                  for(index=4920; index<=6075; index+=5){
                      var opt = document.createElement("option");
                      opt.value= index;
                      opt.innerHTML = index;       
                      selectTag.appendChild(opt);           
                  }
              }
        }
```

```html
<select id="wirelessChannel">
</select>

<select id="country" onchange="fillWirelessChannel()">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks you for response sir.
Yeah, you were right.
Thanks again
:-)

Answer (score 1):

to test if a value is equal to something you need to use a double equal sign - to set a value to something you would use a single equal sign.

```
function fillWirelessChannel(){
    var index;

    var selectTag= document.getElementById('wirelessChannel');
        selectTag.options.length = 0; 

    var auto = document.createElement('option');
        auto.value= 'auto';
        auto.text = 'auto';

    selectTag.appendChild( auto );

    var oCountry=document.getElementById('country');

    if ( oCountry.value==1 ) {
        for( index=4920; index <= 5825; index+=5 ){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value= index;
                opt.text = index;

            selectTag.appendChild( opt );         
        }
    } else if( oCountry.value=='2' ){               
        for( index=4920; index <= 6075; index+=5 ){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value= index;
                opt.text = index;

            selectTag.appendChild( opt );           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There hasn't been a good reason to use *selectedIndex* since some ancient version of Netscape Navigator,  `oCountry.value=='1'` is sufficient.

Comment: ok - I did not know that, I have always used hat syntax ( since the days of NN ) so now I can shorten my code - thanks @RobG

Comment: Funny how those old memes persist. ;-)